# Data structure for fast bi-directional SHA-1 to SHA-3 mapping

Tags: data-structures, hashing, map

What data structure would be best choice for fast and performant bidirectional SHA-1 to SHA-3 mapping?  Or in other words fixed-length string to fixed-length string mapping?

To be more precise:

1. There exists a set of data (which might count in mega-objects), over each of which SHA-1 and SHA-3 hash of is taken
2. For given SHA-1 we want to know if object (data) exists, and its SHA-3 hash function
3. For given SHA-3 we want to know if object (data) exists, and its SHA-1 hash function

The set of data is not immutable, but one can assume that only new data would be added.

Most important is fast query and low overhead; the modification may perform slower.  It would be good if it could perform lock-less updates.  Updates (append only) are much rare than queries, and only need to perform below human reaction time.

---

**Background**: one of proposals of moving Git away from SHA-1 requires fast SHA-1 to SHA-3 (or to whatever hash is chosen to replace broken SHA-1).

See it here: [RFC: Another proposed hash function transition plan](https://public-inbox.org/git/20170304011251.GA26789@aiede.mtv.corp.google.com/)

Comment: This is basically just a poll about how to move away from SHA-1. Furthermore, the answer(s) depend a massive amount on the various constraints, such as needing atomic operations, persistence, performance, etc.

Comment: This question is meant to find out what solutions are possible, and thus if the referenced plan is feasible given constraints Git must work under. I have added a bit of clarification.

Comment: You are describing a database. In relational terms, you want a table representing an 1:1 mapping with an index over both columns. I'm sure there's plenty of R&D into database engines that you could look at for inspiration. The requirements you mention aren't particularly extraordinary.

Comment: So, in other words, if the database with indices approach is a good one, the question is what data structures RDBMS uses for fast indices? On the other hand RDBMS must be more generic, thus less performant than possible.

Comment: I doubt you'll find something much better than two hash-tables, one for each direction. Of course to populate it you need to rehash the original data.

Comment: Since you're specifically interested it Git, you should look at pack files -- the same index could be used to associate different hashes. However, I'm voting to close this question as unclear. It seems on the one hand that you want to pick a data structure for something you're doing, and on the other that you want to evaluate options that the Git team might choose. Or perhaps you're asking something completely different.